# How to purge nested tcl list according to some internal value

Tags: tcl

I have a script with the following format in it:

```
set cmd "some command and -flags -parameters {{{format1} {bla bla} {param:{M1 more info}}} \  
{{format2} {bla bla} {param:{M2 more info}}} \  
...
{{format15} {bla bla} {param:{M15 more info}}}} -extra info"
```

I want to purge all items with M11 and above from the cmd var without impacting the rest of the cmd.

Tried considering it as a list, but I have no guarantee which of the list elements will contain the relevant nested-list.

Is there a nice and easy way to perform this purge, or must I chisel my why through the $cmd variable?

Required output should be:

```
 "some command and -flags -parameters {{{format1} {bla bla} {param:{M1 more info}}} \  
{{format2} {bla bla} {param:{M2 more info}}} \  
...
{{format10} {bla bla} {param:{M10 more info}}}} -extra info"
```

**Edit:**
Using Donnel's answer I got to this solution:

```
for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $cmd]} {incr i} {
    if {[llength [lindex $cmd $i] ] == 1} {continue}
    set filtered [lmap p [lindex $cmd $i] {
    if {[regexp {^parameters:\{M(\d+)} [lindex $p 2] -> val] && $val >= 11} { continue }
    string cat $p
    }]
    break
}
set cmd [string cat [lrange $cmd 0 [expr $i -1]] " " $filtered " " [lrange $cmd [expr $i +1] end]]
```

The beauty is the loop also finds the place in the string where the nested list lies, allowing to concat the strings easily afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely going to be rather messy.

Assuming you've got:

```
set parameters {{{format1} {bla bla} {param:{M1 more info}}} \  
{{format2} {bla bla} {param:{M2 more info}}} \  
...
{{format15} {bla bla} {param:{M15 more info}}}}
```

then we can filter them with `lmap` and `continue`:

```
set filtered [lmap p $parameters {
    if {[regexp {^param:\{M(\d+)} [lindex $p 2] -> val] && $val >= 11} {
        # Skips this item
        continue
    }
    # Don't skip, don't further transform
    string cat $p
}]
```

The resulting list will be equivalent in terms of its elements, except for the items that are removed.

---

I've assumed that the value you're interested in for determining whether to filter is in the third element of each sublist. If it is instead the *last* element then `end` instead of `2` will be more appropriate for the `lindex`. If you have to search for it, that's considerably more expensive! You'd do this:

```
set filtered [lmap p $parameters {
    set idx [lsearch -glob $p param:*]
    if {$idx >= 0 && [regexp {^param:\{M(\d+)} [lindex $p $idx] -> val] && $val >= 11} {
        # Skips this item
        continue
    }
    # Don't skip, don't further transform
    string cat $p
}]
```

But I really hope you don't need to do that! (In theory it could be even more complicated, and your performance will correspondingly suffer.)

Comment: OMG, man - this is one nasty piece of code! Amazing